# Unable to solve with Reduce

Tags: equation-solving

I try to solve the following set of equations but i keep getting the error message "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce". I wonder if the problem is syntax or there is no solution? Thanks

```
    FullSimplify[
 Reduce[λ*d10 + μ*p*d01 <= (λ + μ + β)*
     d10 && λ*d10 + μ*p*
      k <= (λ + μ + β)*d10 && λbar*
     d10 <= (λbar + β)*d01 && λbar*d10 + 
     x*p*μ (k - d01) <= (λbar + β)*
     d01 && λbar*r + 
     x*p*μ (k - d01) <= (λ + β)*d01 && 
   0 < λ < 1 && 0 < μ < 1 && 0 < p < 1 && 
   0 < β < 1 && λ + λbar + β + μ < 1 &&
    d01 >= 0 && d10 >= 0 && r > 0 && k > 0 && d10 <= r && 
   re <= r && x > 0 && p <= pe && 
   d01 <= (r - re) + (1 - pe)*d01, {d10, 
   d01}]]
```

Comment: FindInstance for $\{\text{d10},\text{d01},e,k,p,r,x,\lambda ,\mu ,\beta ,\lambda ,\mu ,\beta ,\text{$\lambda $bar}\} $ says "FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist "

Comment: It was a good idea to subsitute the Subscript-variables by normal varialbles. Now "FindInstance" yields one result, but when I try, to get more, the kernel crashes due to too less memory. May be it would help to reduce the system by one or two parameters.   FindInstance"-results:  {{d10 -> 27/32, d01 -> 1, \[Lambda] -> 1/32, \[Mu] -> 1/2, 
  p -> 1/2, \[Beta] -> 1/2, k -> 1/2, \[Lambda]bar -> -3, x -> 1, 
  r -> 1, pe -> 2, re -> -1}}

Comment: "I wonder if the problem is syntax or there is no solution?"  I thought the message was pretty clear.  The methods built into `Reduce` cannot solve this system.  That does not mean that there is no solution.  It also does not mean that you have a syntax error.

Comment: If you take a much simpler system of inequalities with *this many* parameters, and try to solve it by hand, going through all the possible special cases, that will give you a hint about why it is not very reasonable to expect a solution at all.